# Set User submitted data in Cookie in WordPress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, plugins

After lots of research, I came up with the dilemma that "Is it really possible to store user submitted data in Cookie while developing ***WordPress plugin***?".

While using in normal theme development, we can call the `init` hook which fires before displaying views to avoid `Headers already sent` error.

I am using following code to render my view and store data through ajax in Plugin file:

```
$this->loader->add_action('wp_ajax_store_new_space_data', $plugin_public, 'store_new_space_data');
$this->loader->add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_store_new_space_data', $plugin_public, 'store_new_space_data');
```

When I set cookie inside `store_new_space_data` method, I get the error `header already sent` and `Undefined array key "name"`

```
    public function store_new_space_data($attributes)
    {
        global $wpdb;

        setcookie('name', 'Vijay');

        print_r($_COOKIE['name']);
    }
```

My Goal: When `store_new_space_data` is called, I want to store some user input value in Cookie.

In short:  I am building a plugin. A form is displayed to a user. When the user submit the form, I want to store some values in cookie so that the user can came back 1 week later and see what they entered when they visit earlier.

Comment: Why would you try to do this from within a shortcode function? Executing a shortcode usually is part of the template rendering process, so it is very likely that output has already been created before this point. Your whole description of what you actually want to _achieve_ here, is rather vague.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I agree. I am searching for a starting point. However, below shortcode, I am calling ajax function. Is it possible to set cookies inside that function?

Comment: It is unclear what the shortcode is supposed to have to do with the whole thing in the first place. You need to give a better description of what you actually want to achieve here.

Comment: @CBroe I will try to be as simple as possible. I am building a plugin. A form is displayed to a user. When the user submit the form, I want to store some values in cookie so that the user can came back 1 week later and see what they entered.

Comment: Still does not explain how this is supposed to be tied to the shortcode. Are you using the shortcode to render the form? Then there is still no reason why that shortcode should be “involved” in any way, in processing the submitted data.

Comment: @CBroe I have removed the shortcode. Can you please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231057/discussion-between-vijayrana-and-cbroe).

Comment: A cookie is _not_ available in $_COOKIE directly after you set it, but only after the next request - so that would probably explain your undefined index error here.

Comment: ok that makes some sense, but when I debug in the browser > Inspect Element > Application > Storage > Cookies, I don't see any cookie I created with the same name.

Comment: If you are still getting the headers already sent error, then that is to be expected. (Have you considered setting the cookie on the client side instead, via JavaScript?)

Comment: Well, I am not getting the headers already sent error but neither the cookie is set. I haven't tried via Javascript.